# FosUserBundle how to fix redirect loop

Tags: security, loops, symfony, configuration, fosuserbundle

Hi i have redirect loop after login useing fosuserbundle
how it looks? i type good username and password then it log me in i can see it with symfony profiller
and the profiler says that `This request redirects to http://web.dev/app_dev.php/admin/panel.` i go there and it says `This request redirects to http://web.dev/app_dev.php/admin/login.` and im no longer authenticated in this place

here is my security:

```
jms_security_extra:
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
        MainBundle\Security\User\SsoUser: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    "%api_username%":  { password: "%api_password%", roles: [ 'ROLE_API' ] }     
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        ssoprovider:
            id: sso_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path:                       fos_user_security_login
                check_path:                       fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path:              admin_main
            logout:    
                path: fos_user_security_logout   
                invalidate_session: true #https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5868
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                name:     "web_remember_me"
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 864000 # 10 days
                path:     /admin
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/(?!admin)            
            form_login: 
                login_path : main_user_logout
            stateless: false
            anonymous: false
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: sso_authenticator 
            logout:
                path:   main_user_logout
                invalidate_session: true 
                success_handler: sso_authentication_handler 
        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            stateless:  true
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured API Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api/, roles: ROLE_API }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Have you given the user the role of `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` or `ROLE_ADMIN`? A generated user usually just have the role of `ROLE_USER` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: i got ROLE_ADMIN i overided the methods, the problem appears when i added secured_area and wrote ssoprovider
i use fosuserbundle to authenticated admins and my own custom authenticator to authenticate users

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?  I had a problem very similar to this, turned out if was a bug with how PHP handled sessions.

Comment: 5.4, i already fixed my problem it was becouse i had defined `cookie_domain` and i hade to add in my firewall
`domain: %domain%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused because I had defined in my config.yml `cookie_domain`

config yml:

```
framework:
    session:
      cookie_domain: .%domain%
```

and I had to add for remember me `domain` configuration

security.yml:

```
admin:
    remember_me:
        domain:   ".%domain%"
```